# Populate Highchart with data from a python function

Tags: python, highcharts

I am trying to add data coming from a text file; I don't want to use CSV files, since that would add another step to my workflow, while I would like to know if there is any way for me to process the text file via python, and pass the data to the series in Highcharts.

I see that highcharts runs in a web page, so I can't use python code there.

Is this possible? The data change constantly, which means that I will have to change data often, and using python is easier for me than adding an extra step to format the input from simple text file to CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this libary: https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts which does exactly what you want.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developper of the library.*

Answer (score 0):

You can code a simple web app using something like Django or Flask.

There will be two main URLs in that app: the first one will return the static content of the web, and the second one will return a JSON formatted response with the data you want to plot.

This data has to be AJAX loaded in Highcharts, this is a demo of that: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. So I cannot inject a python output directly into the series; I need to output it as json and then feed highcharts with it. This is all new to me, it is quite daunting :) Probably it takes me less time to just convert the output file from txt to CSV, than learning JSON and AJAX...never touched that stuff in my entire life. Thanks!

Comment: You can parse your data from txt, you need to load file (by $.get()), split your text and prepare correct structure of series object.